# GRAPE-ENTITY ARRAYS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grape-api, grape-entity

I'm using Grape and Grape-Entity library in Ruby on Rails Project to expose my params from backend. Is any possibility to expose two params values in one entity param?

My backend json: `{value: '1', value_second: '2'}`, 
but i want to get `{values: [1,2]}` from my endpoint.

UPDATE!!! - working example

```
camel_case_expose : values

private

def values
  [object.value, object.value_second]
end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Seems like you could just get the value of each property of your object, and push the values to an array.

Comment: by key and value loop ? |k, v| ?